# Play 2.6 I18N Twirl fails in production mode

Tags: scala, playframework, internationalization, twirl, playframework-2.6

When I run my Play 2.6 app in dev mode, it's properly localized to the requested language. However in production mode the placeholders for messages are not  replaced with their actual values. In other words:

in `messages.en` I have:

```
home.location = Germany
```

In my Twirl template I have:

```
@()(implicit messages: MessagesProvider)
...
<span>@messages.messages("home.location")</span>
```

And in controller:

```
class HomeController @Inject()(components: ControllerComponents, langs: Langs)
    extends AbstractController(components)
    with I18nSupport {

  def home: Action[AnyContent] = Action { implicit request =>
    Ok(views.html.home())
  }
}
```

When I run in dev mode, it's rendered as

```
<span>Germany</span>
```

But in prod mode as:

```
<span>home.location</span>
```

This happens when I run in prod mode in SBT and also when I package it with `sbt-native-packager` and run standalone. Am I holding it wrong?

Comment: Did you manage to resolve this issue? If yes, can you please tell us how you did it? Thank you

Comment: Not really, I haven't.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I'm having a similar issue. I'll keep you posted if I manage to resolve it. :)

Comment: That would be most helpful, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You have to put "LauncherJarPlugin" option in build.sbt.

For example, "lazy val root = (project in file (". ")). EnablePlugins (PlayScala, LauncherJarPlugin)"

I had the same problem, but I fixed it like this.

Good luck.

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't help.

Comment: use <span>@Messages("home.location")</span>. Inherit and implement "MessagesAbstractController". I did it like that.

Answer (score 0):

I faced more or less the same issue today. I have `messages` and `messages.pt-br` on my play application. everything was working fine on dev mode but on production only the English (`messages` file) was being loaded.
I noticed that on my `application.conf` file I had:

```
play.i18n.langs = [ "en", "pt-BR"]
```

but my `pt-br` file was named `messages.pt-br`. What I did was to rename it to `messages.pt-BR` and now it works just fine on production.
I suspect the upper case letters in the filename play a big part of it on production.

Try to name them with the language extension exactly like in the `application.conf` and see if it works.